# Unexpected results from SQL query with LATERAL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am executing the following query

```
SELECT 
    val b1, geom, gid, ggeom
FROM
    (SELECT dp.*, g.gid gid, g.geom ggeom
     FROM raster_grid g, public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast,
          LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 1) as dp
     WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)) foo;
```

and get this result

| b1 | geom | gid | ggeom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5135.0 | POINT (300005 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 4994.0 | POINT (300015 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 4515.0 | POINT (300025 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 3942.0 | POINT (300035 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 3428.0 | POINT (300045 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 4364.0 | POINT (300055 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |
| 4796.0 | POINT (300065 5800015) | 63 | POLYGON ((300620 5800010, 300620 5800020, 300630 5800020, 300630 5800010, 300620 5800010)) |

As you may noticed while values in the `geom` column are changing, the values in columns `gid, ggeom` are duplicating which means that is not correct. It should be different, f.e, `gid = 1,2,3,...`. What is wrong in the query?

Comment: I'm not sure what `public.t32ulc_entire_tile` is but are you intentionally cross joining that to `raster_grid`? Is your example output a subset of the actual result set? When you say `SELECT * FROM table1, table2;` That is performing a cross join between `table1` and `table2` which could easily produce duplicates in this manner. I'd bet the problem is in that join and has nothing to do with the `LATERAL` to a function.

Comment: @JSpratt thanks for your response. I am overlapping the `raster_grid` on top of the `public.t32ulc_entire_tile`, to extract values from areas that intersect. Yeah, I have noticed that here is using `CROSS JOIN`. Ideally, the left join should be used as `raster grid left join public.t32ulc_entire_tile on ...`. Any ideas how can I combine with the lateral?

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with the operation you're trying to perform here but I still think it's a `JOIN` problem. Are you trying to say, "Where on the grid does the centroid of this tile intersect?" You might just have to reorder the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. I've updated the answer with another `JOIN` order.

Comment: @JSpratt it is working now., thanks a lot. I have one more concern.  How can I extract other bands from the raster table by `ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 2)` with `ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 1)`. Finally, I should have smth like dp.val, dp.geom, dp2.val, dp.geom, gid, ggeom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom))`, try using the PostGIS intersection operator. `&&` for 2D intersection and `&&&` for 3D intersection. This will replace your `CROSS JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` and still apply the intersection logic:

```
SELECT dp.*
     , dp2.*
     , g.gid gid
     , g.geom ggeom
  FROM public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast
     , LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 1) as dp
  JOIN raster_grid g ON dp.geom && g.geom
 UNION
SELECT dp.*
     , dp2.*
     , g.gid gid
     , g.geom ggeom
  FROM public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast2
     , LATERAL ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast2.rast, 2) as dp2
  JOIN raster_grid g2 ON dp2.geom && g2.geom
;
```

Comment: Seems a very interesting and clear query. I have tried your script with left join, but still I am getting results for cross join.

Comment: The second approach is working now., thanks a lot. I have one more concern. How can I extract other bands from the raster table by ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 2) with ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast.rast, 1). Finally, I should have smth like dp.val, dp.geom, dp2.val, dp.geom, gid, ggeom.

Comment: I think the update I just made should do the trick.

Comment: haha, I have tried that but it gives `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "dp"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "dp", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Position: 236
Error position: line: 83 pos: 235`. If I remove dp it works as a cross join

Comment: I thought it might actually. In that case you can use a `UNION`.